# containverbatim shows up in output

Tags: xetex, pdftex, output

When I compile the following code in XeLaTeX (also works with pdflatex) under windows, `[containsverbatim]` shows up in the ouput:

[image: Ouput]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{book} 
\usepackage{showexpl} 
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[top=5cm, bottom=5cm, left=6cm, right=3cm]{geometry}

\lstloadlanguages{[LaTeX]Tex} 
\lstset{% 
     basicstyle=\ttfamily\small, 
     commentstyle=\itshape\ttfamily\small, 
     showspaces=false, 
     showstringspaces=false, 
     breaklines=true, 
     breakautoindent=true, 
     captionpos=t 
} 

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[containsverbatim] %Problem here

\begin{LTXexample} 

\chapter{Good buy}
\section{haha}
lorem ipsum dolor si amet...lorem ipsum dolor si amet...lorem ipsum dolor si amet...lorem ipsum dolor si amet...lorem ipsum dolor si amet...lorem ipsum dolor si amet...
\end{LTXexample}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

When I don't add `[containsverbatim]` it still works, but it leaves an annoying dot:
[image: Output 2]

I'm surely doing something wrong here, so I appreciate any help.

Comment: The `frame` environment is proper of `beamer`, not of `book` (where `\frame` does a very different thing). There's no mention of `containsverbatim` in the `beamer` manual, though.

Comment: Isn't that  what `\usepackage{showexpl}` suppose to do?

Comment: @egreg `containsverbatim` is I think an old option for `beamer`: it's there in the code, but `fragile` is the supported option name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `containsverbatim` "option" to `frame` is something used in `beamer` which you are not using. Also, the `frame` environment is an inherited construct (actually a regular macro) within LaTeX, hence the fact that there is no error when using it.

If you wish to frame the entire `LTXexample` output, you should use the [`framed`](http://ctan.org/pkg/framed) or [`mdframed`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) packages that respectively provide the `framed` and `mdframed` environments.

Here's an MWE showcasing the use of the former (`framed`) package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{showexpl}% http://ctan.org/pkg/showexpl
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}% http://ctan.org/pkg/babel
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fontenc
\usepackage[top=5cm, bottom=5cm, left=6cm, right=3cm]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{framed}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry

\lstloadlanguages{[LaTeX]Tex} 
\lstset{% 
     basicstyle=\ttfamily\small, 
     commentstyle=\itshape\ttfamily\small, 
     showspaces=false, 
     showstringspaces=false, 
     breaklines=true, 
     breakautoindent=true, 
     captionpos=t 
} 

\begin{document}

\begin{framed}

\begin{LTXexample} 

\chapter{Good buy}
\section{haha}
lorem ipsum dolor si amet...lorem ipsum dolor si amet...lorem ipsum dolor si amet...lorem ipsum dolor si amet...lorem ipsum dolor si amet...lorem ipsum dolor si amet...
\end{LTXexample}

\end{framed}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for very quick response (and for explaining), works perfectly.

Comment: I have a little side question... Is it possible with showexpl to only show the output without the code displaying?

Comment: @bobicool: You don't need `showexpl` to only show the output. LaTeX creates the output by default. Otherwise please explain your intent.

Comment: Well, I posted another question related to what I asked you: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49245/show-output-of-a-full-latex-document maybe you can help me there? Since no has completely answered my question.