# How to illustrate and execute a MWE within another document

Tags: documentation, latex-base

In  [Show output of a full LaTeX document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49245/show-output-of-a-full-latex-document/49248#49248) I provided a partial solution to a similar question. The following code is an attempt to *simulate* the running of a full MWE within another document as for example a tutorial for LaTeX. The code produces an output as per the image below:

[image]

The top part of the box is the code and the bottom part the LaTeX output. The code sandboxes the `begin{document}...\end{document}` macros in order to disable them within the example code and only just typeset them.

**I am looking for a method to import packages or classes at this point and only run them locally within the example. How can this be achieved?**

An approach would be to just let `ProvidesPackage` etc... to empty, disable the `\@preamblecmds` and use `globaldefs` to ensure that the code only runs within a group.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[listings]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\gdef\@preamblecmds{}
\def\documentclass#1{}
\def\usepackage#1{}
\let\Document\document
\let\Enddocument\enddocument
\def\document{}
\def\enddocument{}
\gdef\after@@{\let\enddocument\Enddocument\let\document\Document}
\newenvironment{tex}{
  \tcblisting{boxrule=1pt}}
{\endtcblisting\aftergroup\after@@}
% auto example
\begin{tex}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
 \section{Introduction}
   Whence we conclude that $\gamma$ is a primitive root modulo $p$. But
  \begin{align*}
  \gamma^{p-1}-1 &=
     g^{p-1} - 1 + \frac{p-1}{1!}g^{p-2}xp +
        \frac{(p-1)(p-2)}{2!}g^{p-3}x^2p^2 + \ldots \\
    &= p\left(kp + \frac{p-1}{1!}g^{p-2}x +
        \frac{(p-1)(p-2)}{2!}g^{p-3}x^2p + \ldots\right).
  \end{align*}
\end{document}
\end{tex}
\bigskip
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you work with `--shell-escape`?

Comment: Is there really merit in this approach? It seems so much easier to have a local TeX run for every example. Otherwise, take a look at the `preview` package.

Comment: @StephanLehmke There is merit while you writing the notes and during editing. Also it doesn't seem all that impossible to code.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel I would rather keep the running of the examples within the document and without --shell-escape.

Comment: You are talking about "the following code". Which code? Is it in your answer to the other question?

Comment: I might want to put the `\section` after `\begin{document}` if I were you `:-)`

Comment: @StephanLehmke Code added.

Comment: @ienissei Thanks:) Proof that `\begin{document}` was neutered!

Comment: You should disable `\@preamblecmds` *before* the main `\begin{document}`: when it has acted it's impossible to recover the original definitions of the "preamble only" commands. However, using `\globaldefs=-1` would break all packages that use `\gdef` or `\xdef` for their workings. And what about section numbers and the like? LaTeX relies on the fact that `\stepcounter` acts globally.

Comment: @egreg The idea as per this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49245/show-output-of-a-full-latex-document/49248#49248 is to re-adjust the counters afterwards (as part of the package). Will amend `\@premablecmds`.

Comment: @Yiannis: Thanks for the code. Unfortunately I can't experiment because apparently my TeX Distribution is too old ;-) So I'll just look what comes out of this.

Comment: @StephanLehmke You probably need an update on tcolorbox.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could use the `docmute` package (updated recently). It does what you want, although you still need to reset the counters by hand.

In the MWE, I have used it on your code (written inside the main document), and also on imported code from a `testing.tex` file, which you should create beforehand.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[listings]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,lipsum}

\usepackage{docmute}

\newenvironment{tex}
    {\tcblisting{boxrule=1pt}}
    {\endtcblisting\bigskip}

\newcommand{\inputtex}[1]{\tcbinputlisting{listing file=#1,boxrule=1pt}\bigskip}

\begin{document}

\begin{tex}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
 \section{Introduction}
   Whence we conclude that $\gamma$ is a primitive root modulo $p$. But
  \begin{align*}
  \gamma^{p-1}-1 &=
     g^{p-1} - 1 + \frac{p-1}{1!}g^{p-2}xp +
        \frac{(p-1)(p-2)}{2!}g^{p-3}x^2p^2 + \ldots \\
    &= p\left(kp + \frac{p-1}{1!}g^{p-2}x +
        \frac{(p-1)(p-2)}{2!}g^{p-3}x^2p + \ldots\right).
  \end{align*}
\end{document}
\end{tex}
\setcounter{section}{0}

\lipsum[1]

\inputtex{testing.tex}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```